# Assigning values from 3d tensor to 4d one

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have a 4D tensor, tails, and a 3D one, tail. I want to assign values of 3D tensor to first 'row' of the 4D tensor, but I am not getting any change in values in a tails array.

```
>>> tail.shape
(32,32,3)
>>> tails.shape
(350,32,32,3)
>>> tails[1].shape
(32,32,3)

>>>tails[1] = tail
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexes start at 0 in Python, so to access the first row of `tails` you will need to write `tails[0]`.

Also, there is an answer talking about a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926905/how-to-build-a-tensor-from-one-tensor-of-contents-and-another-of-indices).

Comment: Thank you. I need to assign values for every row, so indexing doesn't play a big role in this example

Comment: Solution provided in the linked post doesn't cut it for me. I can assign values from one (32,32,3) to another one of same dimensions. But I can't assign values from (32,32,3) tensor to the first row (or any row) of (350,32,32,3) tensor